# Pandas: Filtering rows with data in particular column on the separator basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I was trying to return only those rows when any value in column **director** has a separator '|'. But it is not filtering on the separator basis and instead shows all the rows. Please let me know the possible issue with this.

I tried the following:

```
hb_dctr = df_updated[df_updated['director'].str.contains('|')]
hb_dctr
```

But it shows following

```
id      popularity   budget     Cast                        director
135397  32.985763    150000000  Chris Pratt|Irrfan Khan     Colin Trevorrow
76341   28.419936    150000000  Tom Hardy|Charlize Theron   George Miller
76757   6.189369     176000003  Mila Kunis|Channing     Lana Wachowski|Lilly Wachowski
```

It should only show rows that with id *135397* and *766341*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape `|` because special regex character (`or`):

```
df1 = df[df.director.str.contains("\|")]
print (df1)
      id  popularity     budget                      Cast  \
2  76757    6.189369  176000003  Mila Kunis|Channing Lana   

                    director  
2  Wachowski|Lilly Wachowski
```

For not contains use `~`:

```
df2 = df[~df.director.str.contains("\|")]
print (df2)
       id  popularity     budget                       Cast         director
0  135397   32.985763  150000000    Chris Pratt|Irrfan Khan  Colin Trevorrow
1   76341   28.419936  150000000  Tom Hardy|Charlize Theron    George Miller
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.director.str.contains("\|"))
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: director, dtype: bool

print (~df.director.str.contains("\|"))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: director, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `regex=False`

```
df[df.director.str.contains("|",regex=False)]
```

---

```
      id  popularity     budget                 Cast  \
2  76757    6.189369  176000003  Mila Kunis|Channing   

                         director  
2  Lana Wachowski|Lilly Wachowski
```

If you want to exclude such rows, use an invert `~`

```
df[~df.director.str.contains("|",regex=False)]
```

---

```
       id  popularity     budget                       Cast         director
0  135397   32.985763  150000000    Chris Pratt|Irrfan Khan  Colin Trevorrow
1   76341   28.419936  150000000  Tom Hardy|Charlize Theron    George Miller
```